# Use a double integral to find the area of the region.

Tags: calculus, integration

For One loop of the rose r = 6 cos 3θ

So I solved the double integral

$$
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\left(\int_{0}^{6\cos(3\theta)} r\ dr\right)\ d\theta
$$

And I got an answer of $\frac{1}{12}\pi$. At the end of the problem, I got
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{6}\pi + 6\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6^2}\right) - \frac14\left(\frac{-\pi}{6}+6\sin(-\pi)\right)\right) $$

which should be $\frac{1}{12}\pi$ which I am unsure if it is right or not.

Comment: Please improve your question by using Latex formatting.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\left(\int_{0}^{6\cos(3\theta)} r\ \mathrm dr\right)\ \mathrm d\theta$$ 
$$
=18\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos^2(3\theta)\ \mathrm d\theta$$
Since the integrand is an even function, we have
$$
36\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos^2(3\theta)\ \mathrm d\theta$$
Now we can use the fact that
$$
\int \cos^2(ax)\ \mathrm dx=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4a}\sin(2ax)+C
$$
Where in our case $a=3$, therefore
$$
36\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{1}{12}\sin\left(\pi\right)\right)=\frac{36\pi}{12}=3\pi$$